# Echo multidimensional array fields in a for or foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I built a multidimensional array to store some values, and I was able to remove duplicates.

What I want to do now is build a for or foreach loop to echo the subarray values by key, like [0], [1], etc because it seems to have put them in nice rows for me. Print_r shows the data exactly as I need it, but I need to iterate through to build some form buttons for each set.

I use a function I found to generate unique entries from multidimensional arrays, as follows:

```
function multi_unique($array) {
    foreach ($array as $k=>$na)
        $new[$k] = serialize($na);
    $uniq = array_unique($new);
    foreach($uniq as $k=>$ser)
        $new1[$k] = unserialize($ser);
    return ($new1);
}
```

Initializing the array:

```
$unique_array = array(
    'username'=>array(),
    'user_id'=>array(),
    'weeknumber'=>array()
    );
```

Building the array from within a while loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$unique_array[] = array('username'=>$row['username'], 'user_id'=>$row['user_id'], 'weeknumber'=>$row['weeknumber']);
}
```

And finally, I need to make sure the array values are unique (there are duplicates entries as a result of database and query limitations), after the while loop I have:

```
print_r(multi_unique($unique_array));
```

Which produces output like this on the page with print_r, generated dynamically from the database with duplicate entries removed:

```
Array ( [username] => Array ( ) [0] => Array ( [username] => username1 [user_id] => 58 [weeknumber] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [username] => username2 [user_id] => 21 [weeknumber] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [username] => username3 [user_id] => 24 [weeknumber] => 1 )
```

Like I said, everything goes into the array swimmingly, I just need a good way to pull everything out once again, I need the username, user_id, and weeknumber to echo within a loop.

Any help is appreciated!

And yes, I know mysql is deprecated, but it's too late in the game to change that now + I'm working off existing code by someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop through the array and each iteration of the loop will be the next array in the `unique_array`

```
foreach($unique_array as $row){
   // Format this as desired
   echo $row['username'] . $row['user_id'] . $row['weeknumber'];
}
```

Comment: Can this be combined with the multi_unique() function as well? Maybe I can do something like $unique_array = multi_unique($unique_array) first?

Comment: Do you mean `array_unique()`? Why not make your SQL return unique rows?

Comment: Ha! You are correct! I added this gem I found into the code and forgot about it. I'll post it up top.

Comment: DISTINCT won't work in this case, because the rows aren't exactly distinct, I tried, which lead me to this solution, ha.

Comment: With a slight modification for formatting, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization code is incorrect, it should be:

```
$unique_array = array();
```

To pull everything out, use:

```
foreach ($unique_array as $user) {
  echo "Username: " . $user['username'] . "\n";
  echo "UserID: " . $user['user_id'] . "\n";
  echo "Week Number: " . $user['weeknumber'] . "\n";
  echo "\n";
}
```